# Special notation for power series, subscripts on fractions, etc.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, notation

I am attempting to read "Numerical Methods for Special Functions" by Nico M. Temme, however I need help understanding some notation, and I'm not sure where to go to learn this notation. I saw nothing like it in my Stewart Calculus book in the chapter on series. I have two confusions I need help with:

1. what is the subscript on the fraction (1/3) and (2/3) in the series below? I have never seen a subscript on a number like that, only for unspecified coefficients like $c_n$ for example
2. what is $(\alpha)_k$ referring to in this context?
3. Is there a good textbook that explains this kind of notation so I don't have to run and bother you guys next time? All I have is Stewart.

From page 2:
"For the not-so-elementary functions, the same types of limitations occur when using series (Chapter 2). Take for instance the very important case of the Airy functions, which are solutions of the second order ordinary differential equation

y''(z)  - zy(z) = 0

We can try the power series to find the general solution. Substituting $ y(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ we readily see that $a_{2+3n} = 0, n \in N$, and that two linearly independent solutions are

$$ y_1(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^k  \left({1 \over 3}\right)_k {z^{3k} \over (3k)!} $$

$$ y_2(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^k \left({2 \over 3}\right)_k {z^{3k+1} \over (3k + 1)!} $$

where $(\alpha)_0 = 1, (\alpha)_k = \alpha(\alpha + 1)...(\alpha + k - 1), k \ge 1.$"

End quote

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Ok you have cleared everything up for me. Thank you sir!

Comment: Also note that the line about $(\alpha)_k$ is exactly there to define the subscript notation (i.e. $\alpha$ could be any number). So the text is readable without knowing what the notation means beforehand.

Comment: @Milten I see that now. It just didn't click for me the first time I read it.